# Enabling HTTPS certificate with certbot for ngix makes my webpage 404

Tags: nginx, server, http-status-code-404

Im enabling HTTPS on my web server through the certbot --ngix command. All went well but now browsing to the website it comes up with a 404 error.

Comment: Can you add more information? Like Nginx config block generated by certbot for that website?

Comment: Please post your nginx sites-enabled config server blocks and a few examples on how to produce the 404 Not Found error. Nginx error_log is also probably would be helpful.